# SQL Date - functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, weekday, datepart

```
   >=DateAdd("ww",-9,Date()-Weekday(Date(),0)+1))
```

I have the above function in some SQL coding that I have inherited and am struggling to work out what it is actually calculating can anyone help?

Comment: It looks more like an MS Excel or Access function.

Comment: I thought this was DAX, but it's not, since DAX has no `DATEADD` function. But T-SQL has no `WEEKDAY` function, so this is probably just plain VBA. Add the context for where you found this code.

Comment: Could these be user defined SQL functions?

Comment: @Alex: no, because invoking such functions requires specifying the schema (`dbo.Date`). This is not T-SQL.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, how could I have forgotten this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this SQL with the statement deconstructed into parts.
It was tested in sql-server 12, and uses the GETDATE() instead of the Date() function.

```sql
select 
GETDATE() as today, 
@@DATEFIRST as first_day_of_the_week_number,
DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) as current_day_number_of_the_week, 
GETDATE()-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) as previous_saturday, 
GETDATE()-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())+1 as previous_sunday,
DATEADD("ww",-9,GETDATE()-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())+1) as previous_sunday_9_weeks_back;
```

So it would give the sunday of 9 weeks back.

Note that it assumes that `@@DATEFIRST` equals 7.
If `@@DATEFIRST` equals 1 then it would return the monday of 9 weeks back.

Comment: That actually depends entirely on the value of [`@@DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187766). (But the `WeekDay` function is likewise ambiguous with a second argument of `0`.)

Comment: @Jeroen Wasn't aware of that t-sql quirck. Thanks for the insight.